# what are the differences between PHP base64_encode and *nix base64

Tags: php, encoding, base64

PHP's `base64_encode` is returning a different string to the linux `base64` command.
Why is this?

PHP:

```
$ php
<?php
echo base64_encode('test');
?>
dGVzdA==
```

Linux base64:

```
$ echo 'test' | base64
dGVzdAo=
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`echo` usually outputs a new line character at the end of the string, to suppress that use the `-n` switch:

```
$ echo -n 'test' | base64
dGVzdA==
```

Or even better, use the portable `printf`:

```
$ printf 'test' | base64
dGVzdA==
```

Similarly for PHP:

```
$ php <<PHP
<?php echo base64_encode("test\n"); ?>
PHP
dGVzdAo=
```

Answer (score 11):

open console in your browser, type `atob('dGVzdAo=')`:

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/68d16f666c394887929408c519ac1b23.png))</sub>

You have extra character in your input. And that is `0x0A` (LF).

Comment: +1 for [`atob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.atob), that was new to me.

Comment: By the way, that function is not part of any standard, so don't think about using it in production

Comment: @M28 **offtopic**: its in the standard: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/webappapis.html#atob and for IE you can use simple library with those two functions (plenty of implementations exist: [1](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_crypt_base64.js.source.html), [2](http://code.google.com/p/stringencoders/source/browse/trunk/javascript/base64.js?r=230), [3](https://bitbucket.org/davidchambers/base64.js/src), [4](https://gist.github.com/1284012)).

Comment: @c69 That's really weird, in the mozilla site it says `Not part of any standard` (See Ilmari's link)

Answer (score 9):

When doing an echo it gives me this:

```
MacPro:~ bardiir$ echo 'test'
test
MacPro:~ bardiir$
```

I'd guess you might have an included line-ending in the unix one as echo is probably appending a newline character even if you pipe it throuch to the base64 encode.

Comment: Correct explanation, thank you but I'm going to give the solution to knittl as he gave the workaround of "-n".

Comment: Sure, was a new one for me too :)

Answer (score 2):

The linux `base64` has a new line at the end.

Answer (score 2):

It is because Unix version encodes also the end of line.

To receive similar effect in PHP you will have to do something like that:

```
echo base64_encode('test'.PHP_EOL);
```

which will output:

```
dGVzdAo=
```

See the proof here: [ideone.com/HorVD](http://ideone.com/HorVD)

**EDIT:** As Charles mentioned, `PHP_EOL` is platform-specific, so to check the above on Windows you will have to replace it with Unix-like end of line symbol:

```
echo base64_encode("test\n");
```

Comment: Watch out, `PHP_EOL` is *platform-specific* and will be different on Windows.

Comment: @Charles: Thanks, I updated my answer with your notice. I though it would be more meaningful, as he encodes Linux's end of line with Linux's `base64`, and using platform's end of line would be the most appropriate. I wonder however, if something similar is possible on Windows (eg. using PowerShell?, maybe with different syntax, but also resulting in string being processed with end of line, but this time Windows' one).

Comment: It looks like [base64ing can be done](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/04/25/583265.aspx) on strings in PowerShell.  Judging from the fact that it's working on the string instead of on the output of a specific command, there's *probably* no dangling newlines there to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

The same to above guys.

In mac os X, just test this :

```
$ echo  'test' | cat -e

test$
```

Or,

```
$ echo -n  'test' | cat -e

test
```

And,about the echo command, can see the tip:

[echo -e option in ubuntu doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150003/echo-e-option-in-ubuntu-doesnt-work)

Comment: What is the reason for having to pipe through cat?