# echo -e option in ubuntu doesn't work

Tags: shell, ubuntu, makefile

My colleague use Ubuntu and I use openSUSE, we compiled same source code using same makefile, my environment works well, but my colleague can't, always output the can't recognized `-e` option. We check the makefile, ONLY find `echo` command use `-e` option.

Dose Ubuntu's echo function is different with others?

+++++update
in makefile, the echo define as:

`TOOLSDIR =`

`ECHO = $(TOOLSDIR)echo -e`

The $(TOOLSDIR) is dir for tool, this make file can detect compile env, if linux or has CYGWIN:

`$(TOOLSDIR)`is empty, if windows, it will goes to WIN32 version echo tool dir, like:

`TOOLSDIR = $(subst /,\,$(MAKEDIR)/tools/WIN32/)`

after we execute make, ubuntu will output:

Fatal error: L3900U: Unrecognized option '-e'.

however, openSUSE doesn't have this error

+++++update for echo -e

I write a test makefile in ubuntu

```
all:
    echo -e hello
```

it output:

echo -e hello

hello

+++++update makefile test in openSUE (**12.1**) and ubuntu (**12.04**)

```
all:
    echo -e "hello 1"
    echo -e hello 2
    echo -e he\nllo3
    echo -e "he\nllo4"
```

1. opensuse, the output is:

echo -e "hello 1"

hello 1

echo -e hello 2

hello 2

echo -e he\nllo3

henllo3

echo -e "he\nllo4"

he

llo4

1. in ubuntu, the output is:

echo -e "hello 1"

-e hello 1

echo -e hello 2

hello 2

echo -e he\nllo3

henllo3

echo -e "he\nllo4"

-e he

llo4

Meanwhile, i test in ubuntu, echo without `-e`, the result is same as in openSUSE, echo with `-e`

Comment: Can you paste the exact error with context? `echo` in ubuntu supports `-e`, it must be something else.

Comment: Are you both using the same shell interpreter? Bash/Sh?

Comment: Please try a minimal makefile: `all:<cr><tab>echo -e hello` and tell us the result.

Comment: @Diego Basch, i update my error context for you

Comment: @Beta, I post my test makefile for you

Comment: On my Ubuntu box: `sh` invokes `dash` which has `echo` that doesn't support `-e`.

Comment: remove the `$(TOOLSDIR)` in `ECHO = $(TOOLSDIR)echo -e` program `/bin/echo` usually don't accept `-e` while bash does.

Comment: @Luigi R. Viggiano, sorry, my mistake, I checked the code, in linux system build, `$(TOOLSDIR)` is empty already, see my correction in question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could depend from the shell you guys are using (echo is often implemented inside the shell)

this is what happens in OS X (Mountain Lion):

```
$ bash
bash-4.2$ echo -e foo
foo
bash-4.2$ sh
sh-3.2$ echo -e foo
-e foo
```

The same for OpenSUSE, and Ubuntu.

`-e` option is not compliant to POSIX (I'm not sure, but it should be the default behavior), btw, to print formatted text, `printf` is more appropriate command.

From the information you provide, it looks to me that your makefile has a bug (portability issue).

On OSX `man echo` doesn't list the `-e` option too, btw. On Ubuntu 12.10 the `-e` is present on my computer, on my router BusyBox v1.13.4 also accepts the `-e` (it's internal command for busybox)

But probably it's just the `/bin/sh` using internal command and ignoring it.

==== UPDATE:

In your makefile remove the $(TOOLSDIR) in front of echo:

```
ECHO = echo -e
```

in fact if you specify the path of the echo (i.e. `/bin/echo`) you force the shell to execute the program from the filesystem instead of the one implemented internally by the shell:

```
$ echo -e foo
foo
$ /bin/echo -e foo
-e foo
```

Comment: my colleague and I use bash not sh

Comment: also, i corrected my question, the `TOOLSDIR` is empty in linux build

Comment: you can see my test in ubuntu and opensuse of echo with `-e`

Comment: also, i test `echo -e foo` and `/bin/echo -e foo`, the output are the same in ubuntu **12.04**

Comment: thanks for your answer and I also find something in `/bin/sh`, pls see my answer

Answer (score 1):

I also find it may cause by ubuntu link `/bin/sh` to `dash` but NOT `bash`. After I use `bash`, problem solved and there is an other question related to this, which I asked:
[same shell script has different behaviou on different Linux distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093506/same-shell-script-has-different-behaviou-on-different-linux-distribution)

Answer (score 1):

Both Luigi R. Viggiano and How Chen provide good explanations to the problem and solutions to it. In fact, their answers complement each other.

In *dash*, the *echo* command does not accept the *-e* flag. However, in *bash*, it does.

In Ubuntu, one might consider using *update-alternatives* to select *bash*, rather than *dash*, as the default shell. The following commands will do the trick (warning, these commands will apply system-wide):

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /bin/sh sh /bin/bash 0
sudo update-alternatives --install /bin/sh sh /bin/dash 0
sudo update-alternatives --set sh /bin/bash
```

Answer (score -1):

The `\` is the escape character in the shell, so `\n` is just that, an "n", so escape the escape `\\\n`.

```
[sg@Study ~]$ echo -e \\nfoo\\nfoo

foo
foo
[sg@Study ~]$
```

or use quotes

```
[sg@Study ~]$ echo -e "\\nfoo\\nfoo"

foo
foo
[sg@Study ~]$
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and I also find something in `/bin/sh`, pls see my answer