# Same shell script has different behaviour on different Linux distributions

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, opensuse

I simply wrote a shell script to make me compile my code easily. My directory tree looks like:

```
TOPDIR
|
+--- DIR[1]
.
.
.
+--- DIR[n]
|
+--- DIR[n+1]
      |
      +--- makefile
```

I used to use following command to compile my code:

```
$cd DIR[n+1]
$make
```

because I want to go back to TOPDIR after compile the code, therefore, I type:

```
$cd -
```

I want to make it in one shell script file, so I write:

```
#! /bin/sh
cd $HOME/$WORKDIR/$MAKEDIR
make
cd -
```

It works well, after this, I got new code from our vendor and it changed something in make process. The directory tree looks almost same as previous but it uses a shell script to start the make process:

```
TOPDIR
|
+--- DIR[1]
|
+--- DIR[2]
.
.
.
+--- DIR[N]
      |
      +--- DIR[n]
      |     |
      |     +---build_1.sh
      +---build_2.sh
```

In build_1.sh, it just contain:

```
#! /bin/sh
source ../build_2.sh
```

therefore, I first use:

```
$cd DIR[n]
$./build_1.sh
```

after compile, I use:

```
$cd -
```

but I write my command in script:

```
#! /bin/sh
cd DIR[n]
./build_1.sh
cd -
```

it shows me:

```
./build_1.sh: 2: ./build_1.sh: source: not found
```

I use same script on `openSUSE`; it has no problem.  But on `ubuntu-13.04`, its pop up above error. I tested the `source` function in `ubuntu-13.04`, no problem for use.

Any comment on this issue?

Comment: wide guess here: In ubuntu, /bin/sh is linked to /bin/dash. Change the shebang to /bin/bash and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: @Paulo Scardine, many thanks!! it works, can I know the different between `bash` and `dash`

Comment: I've made a full answer, hope to help other people in the future.

Comment: I would suggest that using `cd -` in the script is sub-optimal.  You should use a sub-shell to avoid the need to do `cd -`.  If you do `(cd dir[N+1]; make)`, the sub-shell runs in the sub-directory, but the parent shell hasn't changed directory at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu, the default shell `/bin/sh` is a symbolic link to `/bin/dash` - `bash` and `dash` have enough functionality in common that most people never realize the difference, but they are not identical (dash is meant to be lighter).

> The Debian Almquist shell (dash) is a Unix shell, much smaller than Bash, but it is still aiming at POSIX-compliance. It requires less disk space, but it is also less feature-rich. - Wikipedia

You should be safe while sticking to POSIX syntax, but if your script is using features that are only available in `bash`, be sure to change the shebang from `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash` to avoid trouble with systems where `/bin/sh` is not `bash`.

So my advice is: never assume bash is the default shell, stick to syntax from the POSIX standard if you can or explicitly point to `/bin/bash` at the shebang.